# Minimum deployment target for app slicing to be enabled?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-thinning

I'm currently building an iOS application with minimum deployment target set to iOS 8. When users with iOS 9 and later download the app through the app store, do they automatically receive the app-sliced version of my app, or do I have to increase my deployment target?